# Cannot instaniate module AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, error-handling

The problem I've got is that my application can't instaniate my module, due to $routeProvider.

Herer is my controller:

```
var gameApp = angular.module("gameApp", []);

gameApp.controller("firstPageCtrl", function($scope,$http,$location) {
    $scope.doLogin = function() {
        $http.post("lib/action.php", {username: $scope.username, password: $scope.password}).success(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }).error(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    };
});

gameApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider

    .when('/', {
            templateUrl : 'partials/firstpage.html',
            controller  : 'firstPageCtrl'
    })

    .when('/game', {
            templateUrl : 'partials/game.html',
            controller  : 'gameCtrl'
    });
});


gameApp.controller("gameCtrl", function($scope,$http,$location) {

});
```

I can't see the error in my code. Any one?

Here is the error message:

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module gameApp due to: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $routeProvider
```

Here is my index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="gameApp">
<head>
<script src="js/angular.js"></script>
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<meta content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="content-type" />
<script src="js/mastercontroller.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="layout">
    <div id="topcontent">
    </div>
    <div id="middlecontent" ng-controller="firstPageCtrl">
        <div ng-view></div>
    </div>
    <div id="bottomcontent">
        {{"AngularJS"}}
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: added an answer, that should work for you.

Comment: Duplicated question, i've already answered you here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25446969/error-in-my-angularjs-application/25449397#25449397

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to load the angular-route script into your HTML page.

```
  <script src="angular-route.js">
```

(This URL may not be the exact one for your situation, but you get the idea).

Then you need to declare a dependency to the `ngRoute` module.

```
var gameApp = angular.module("gameApp", ['ngRoute']);
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because there is no provider of `$routeProvider`.

Say something like bellow

```
gameApp.config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider

    .when('/', {
            templateUrl : 'partials/firstpage.html',
            controller  : 'firstPageCtrl'
    })

    .when('/game', {
            templateUrl : 'partials/game.html',
            controller  : 'gameCtrl'
    });
}]);
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer, but that don't work either. I get the same error.