# Error in my angularjs application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, error-handling

I get the following error message when I'm trying to navigate to my angularjs app:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.22/$injector/unpr?p0=linkProvider%20%3C-%20link w/<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js:6:443 gc/l.$injector<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js:36:139 c@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js:34:204 gc/p.$injector<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js:36:209 c@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js:34:204 d@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js:34:418 f/<.instantiate@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js:35:101 Pd/this.$get</<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js:67:249 v/<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js:53:373 r@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js:7:369 v@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js:53:237 g@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js:47:117 g@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js:47:117 u/<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js:46:255 fc/c/</<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js:18:200 Zd/this.$get</k.prototype.$eval@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js:112:4 Zd/this.$get</k.prototype.$apply@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js:112:269 fc/c/<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js:18:158 d@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js:34:474 fc/c@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js:18:66 fc@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js:18:270 Xc@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js:17:359 @https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js:214:78 n.Callbacks/j@https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2:27128 n.Callbacks/k.fireWith@https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2:27898 .ready@https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2:29742 K@https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2:30052
```

I have clicked on the link, but Can't see what the problem is.

Here is my controller:

```
var gameApp = angular.module("gameApp", ['ngRoute','ngSanitize']);

gameApp.directive('mapActivity', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch('tabledata', function() {

             angular.element('.click#1').addClass('dotted').html($("<img src='images/dot.png'>"));          
                var j = null;
                for(var i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
                {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'GET',
                        url: 'lib/terrain.php',
                        dataType: 'html',
                        data: {i: i},
                        success: function(data) {
                            var randomRuta = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
                            angular.element('.click#'+randomRuta).addClass('monster').html($("<img src='images/blackdot.png' title='"+data+"'>"));                  
                        },
                        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { alert(thrownError); }
                    });
                    j=i;
                }  
                angular.element('.click').click(function() {
                    if(angular.element(this).hasClass('monster'))
                    {
                        if(confirm('Vill du anfalla monster?'))
                        {
                            alert("Du vann");
                            angular.element('.click.monster'+j).empty();
                            angular.element('.click.monster').removeClass('monster'+j);

                            angular.element('.click.dotted').empty();
                            angular.element('.click.dotted').removeClass('dotted');
                            angular.element(this).addClass('dotted');
                            angular.element('.click.dotted').html($('<img src="images/dot.png">'));
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        angular.element('.click.dotted').empty();
                        angular.element('.click.dotted').removeClass('dotted');

                        if(!angular.element(this).hasClass('dotted'))
                        {
                            angular.element(this).addClass('dotted');
                            angular.element(this).html($('<img src="images/dot.png">'));
                        }
                    }
                });
            });                     
        }
    };
});

function makeTableFrom(str) {
    var k = 1;
    result = "";

    for(var i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
        result += '<tr>';

        for(var j = 1; j <= 20; j++) {
            if(str[k] == '#') {
                result += '<td id=' + k + '">#</td>';
            }
            else if(str[k] == '&') {
                result += '<td class="click" val="water" id="' + k + '">&</td>';
            }
            else {
                result += '<td class="click" id="' + k + '"></td>';
            }

            k++;
        }
        result += '</tr>';
    }
    return result;
}

gameApp.controller("gameCtrl", function($scope,$http,link,$location,$sce,$rootScope) {
    $scope.resultLoaded = false;
    $scope.getMonsters = "1";
    var tabledata = ""; //Variable to store pattern for html table

    $http.post("../lib/action.php", {monsters: $scope.getMonsters}).success(function(data) {    
        //tabledata = data; //Assign the pattern
        $scope.result = makeTableFrom(data); //Call the function to build the table based on the pattern
        $scope.resultLoaded = true;
    }).error(function(data) { console.log("error"); });
    console.log(tabledata);

    $scope.safeHtml = function() {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.result);
    };
    if(link.user) {
        /*$scope.message = "fisk";
        console.log(link.user);*/
    } else {
        /*$scope.message = "Ledsen fisk";
        console.log("Är inte satt");*/
    }
});
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="gameApp">
<head>
<meta content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="content-type" />
</head>
<body ng-controller="gameCtrl">
<div ng-if='resultLoaded'>
    <table ng-bind-html="safeHtml()" map-Activity>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
</tml>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.22/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.22/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script src="../js/gamecontroller.js"></script>
```

As I said, I've clicked on the link to see what the error is caused by, but I can't understand what it is. Anyone who can help me?

Comment: On the _gameCtrl_ you have `function($scope,$http,link,...`, that `link` dependency is what is causing the error. Since Angular cannot find a provider for that dependency it generates an error. Is `link` a service? If yes, make sure it is loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made one plunker example using your code...

I changed the app a bit just to make a better architeture, i dont know if you are doing your app in the way you posted your code here, but if you are, I strongly recommend you to change this, because in a short time you will have greate headaches to maintain your code...

Anyway, take a look at my plunker... [link to plunker gameApp example](http://plnkr.co/edit/5F7MosAujF67x4AY5WKS?p=preview)

Pay attention to the details, for example, the DI (dependence injection) on controller:

**controllers.js file**

```
angular.module('gameApp_controllers')
    .controller('gameCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', '$sce', '$rootScope', 'link',
         function($scope, $http, $location, $sce, $rootScope, link){
             // controller content
}]);
```

Also, the app.js file is more clean, you only declare your app and the modules you need

**app.js**

```
var gameApp = angular.module("gameApp", [
  'ngRoute',
  'ngSanitize',
  'gameApp_controllers',
  'gameApp_directives',
  'gameApp_services'
]);

angular.module('gameApp_controllers', []);
angular.module('gameApp_directives', []);
angular.module('gameApp_services', []);
```

After that you can create one file for each thing (controllers, services, directives, routes, etc) or you can create multiple files for multiple things (usersController.js, fooController.js, etc...)

How you will organize your app is up to you, but in this way, the app get a more clean structure and is more easy to comprehend...

Just one more thing:

> The code is failing because the controller's injector can't find a way
>   to fulfill the request for a service called "link". Are you trying to
>   reference the link function in the directive as a service?

Yes, this is true, you didn't had one "link" service, also you didn't had made the DI in your controller...

Answer (score 0):

The code is failing because the controller's injector can't find a way to fulfill the request for a service called "link".  Are you trying to reference the link function in the directive as a service?

I don't see any reference to a user in your link function, so perhaps you have another service available elsewhere named link that is not being created correctly, or perhaps you typed link when you meant some other existing service.

Hope that helps.